# Copy a read program into a write program Python

Tags: python, readfile, writefile

```
def SpecialCharacter():

'opening read file'

      with open('CS210_Project_Three_Input_File.txt', 'r') as f:

         groceries = f.read().splitlines()  

     frequencies = {}

     for grocery in groceries:

      if grocery not in frequencies:

         frequencies[grocery] = 0
            
      frequencies[grocery] += 1

    for grocery in frequencies:

      print(grocery, frequencies[grocery])
```

I am trying to take the above modified read file and copy it to the below write file.

```
with open('frequency.dat','w') as wf:    
  for line in f:
     wf.write(line)
```

Comment: PLEASE STOP SHOUTING at us.

Comment: first post ever sorry.

Comment: Hi do you  have any traceback, can you desribe a bit more your problem ?

Comment: Good Morning; I'm working on a project that combines c++ and Python.  'CS210_Project_Three_Input_File.txt', 'r' is the original file that I was told to "read."  
 This file has a list of groceries.  The code describes the grocery list and how many times an item is referenced.  example: Pears 3.  Once that was complete ,I was instructed to take that modifiedy read file and write it to frequency.dat.